# Cone equation through the parabola

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming

How to write an equation of cone formed by lines passing through the point $K(a,b,c)$ and intersecting the parabola $y^{2}=2px, z=0$ ?

Comment: It doesn't seem at first glance the data will uniquely specify a cone.  Although lines of the cone pass through the given common point, $K(a,b,c)$, intersections with the parabola would seem restricted to the $x,y$ plane.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The vertex of the cone must be some $V=(-v,0,u)$, a generatrix is parallel to $x$ axis and the opposite generatrix passes through the origin.

Comment: Related: ["What is the cone of the conic section?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/887011/409). In particular, see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/887445/409), which covers the case of an ellipse; adapting the construction for a parabola is an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The parametric equation of the parabolic cross section is

$ p(t) = ( 2 p t^2, 2 p t,  0 )$

lines connecting $K$ to $p(t)$ has the parametric equation

$ q(t,s) = K + s (p(t) - K) $

Now

$p(t) - K = ( 2 p t^2 - a, 2 pt - b , - c) \\
      = (-a, -b, -c) + t (0, 2 p , 0) + t^2 (2p, 0, 0 ) $

Take the vector $[1, t, t^2]$. It lies on the quadric

$[1  , t , t^2]  Q  [ 1, t , t^2 ]^T = 0$ (Identically zero, $\forall t$)

Suppose $Q$ is given by

$Q =\begin{bmatrix} a  && d &&  e\\    d &&   b  &&  f
 \\    e &&  f &&  c \end{bmatrix} $

This results in

$ a + 2 d t + 2 e t^2  + b t^2 + 2 f t^3 + c t^4 = 0 $

which implies that $ a = d = f = c = 0 $ and $ b = - 2 e $.

So a possible $Q$ is

$Q =\begin{bmatrix} 0  && 0 &&  1\\    0 &&   -2  &&  0
 \\    1 &&  0 &&  0 \end{bmatrix} $

So, now we have the following situation,

$p(t) - K = A u $

where $ A = \begin{bmatrix} -a && 0 && 2 p \\ -b && 2 p && 0 \\ -c && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

and $ u = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ t \\ t^2 \end{bmatrix}$

And as derived above, we have $ u^T Q u = 0 $ which implies that

$ \bigg( A^{-1} (p(t) - K) \bigg)^T Q \bigg( A^{-1} (p(k) - K) \bigg) = 0 $

Therefore, the equation of the desired cone is

$ ( q - K)^T Q_1 (q - K) = 0 $

where $ Q_1 = A^{-T} Q A^{-1} $