# Detailed List Of Conic Sections

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

Is there a detailed list of conic sections, with their parametrization, Implicit function, first and second fundamental form?

Comment: You might want to check out this [document](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/Handlin.pdf) titled "Conic Sections Beyond $\mathbb{R}^2$".

Comment: the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) seems to be already quite complete, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe helpful MSE reference: [Confusion with the various forms of the equation of second degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34308/confusion-with-the-various-forms-of-the-equation-of-second-degree) .

Answer (score 1):

First and second fundamental forms are entities associated with a *surface* in 3-space whereas the term *conic section* usually refers to a *curve*. A fairly detailed treatment of ellipses, hyperbolas, parabolas as well as discussion of degenerate cases can be found in my class notes for differential geometry [here](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/egreglong.pdf) (see sections 2.6, 2.7 and following there).

Comment: Thanks, I have taken your course this year :)